# Huge point cloud laser data in PostGIS - Storing and Processing it

Tags: postgis, postgresql, lidar

I wonder, how it's possible to store huge sets of laser scanned point cloud data in PostGIS, with the time-aspect for processing it in mind. I know, there exists a geometry-object `Point` in PostGIS. But as far as I know it saves each point in a new tupel, which can make searching for any certain point a very slow process, if a few millions or more of them are stored.

I found a paper from HSR Universtiy of Applied Sciences Rapperswill, discussing this topic. It suggests three ways to store such data: `Whole data in one tupel`, `Each point in one tupel` or `Splitting Data into Blocks` which are referenced by info-tables, holding the extends of each block. As the third way seems the most useful for locating stored points, I wonder if anyone already has made some experiences with it?

The paper can be found here: http://wiki.hsr.ch/Datenbanken/files/pgsql_point_cloud.pdf

Last but not least, I stumpled across a project on github, which seems to deal with point cloud manners in PostgeSQL. Unfortunately not much information about it around the net. So the same question here: Has someone already made some experiences with it? Is it usable for such purposes?

Project can be found here: https://github.com/pramsey/pointcloud

I would also be glad to hear about other suggestions, ideas or experiences, if there are any. But i must admit, that non-commercial solutions are prefered.

Comment: Could you give a rough idea of what you mean by huge, and what kind of information from the point cloud do you need? I.e. only XYZ and intensity, which could e.g. be stored in blocked MultipointZM or also other attribute data which probably requires Point to get unique values for each separate point measurement?

Comment: I am not convinced that "just" some million points XYZ degrade PostGIS performance significantly and will only believe it if I see a benchmark.

Comment: i store lidar in 10x10 meters multipoints by classification. We use only ground Z values

Comment: @Torsti  Well, I'm talking about several point clouds of street surfaces, each with an extend of about 5x100m². Density of points varies from 4 to 10mm. This gives for every point file an amount of around 9million points. For now it is only xyz and i, but timestamps of each point should be propably added within the point files too. But as far as i know, there is no unique value planned. I will give a further try on your suggestion, thanks.

Comment: @til_b If store all points in one tupel, it seems to appear that for a simple spatial operation whole point data must be loaded into memory. Also single updates, deletes etc. become difficult.  If you store each point in a seperated tupel and have millions ore even billions (regarding to the lenght of the scanned road) the time for 3D-querying could take too long for use in practise - I didnt tried but at least i can easily imagine.

Comment: @simplexio  the multipoint-idea seems to be very useful, as already mentioned for Torsti, and i will definitively give it a look. Thanks u too.

Comment: The "a huge blob in the db" method seems to be bad.
The "many small blobs with bboxes in the db" idea seems to be not-so-bad.
I would try to create something using "one tupel per point" and clever spatial indexing. But I don't have a server to test this on at hand.
I would be very interested in the results!

Comment: in my multipoint solution i use FME workbench to fetch only needed areas when i need to get z for my lines. st_intersect(lines, poincloud) . It limits needed data a lot

Comment: @simplexio did you try using full datasets and have experienced unacceptable performance?

Comment: @AndreSilva The aim is, to generate roads surface profiles out of the data. For now we transformed points into DEM-grids and used PostGIS to store them as rasterblocks and SAGA to create finally the profiles from it. It runs for testing purposes, but it also means a loss in accuracy through rastering the data before db import. Also the export of the grid-cells, cutted by the given profile lines goes very slowly in PostGIS(thanks to ST_Union). Would be nice if you could recommend tools for similar tasks.

Comment: client programs have problems to read over 4G Laz data. and we only need  height (z-value ) where we have pipes. So it just decided to limit data.

Comment: @til_b That's exactly what I had in mind also. Each point has an own tupel. Sum of points is splitted into blocks and bboxes are used to locate the affected points wihtin the blocks more quick. Could turn out as a usable workaround.

Comment: @simplexio Did i understood correctly: You use FME to fetch affected tiles from within all 10x10m² tiles? If so, I think such fetching could be done within PostGIS, while storing an envelope or bbox, holding the geometry of each tile seperatly.

Comment: @AndreSilva  Well yes, and no. We have complete lidar-data, but it represents only the road surface, because the road is directly scanned from a moving vehicle. And since we need exactly this data for the profiles there can be not much filtered out.

Comment: @knutella like this: http://www.spiegel.de/wissenschaft/technik/laserscanner-scannt-strassenschaeden-und-schlagloecher-im-asphalt-a-892293.html ?

Comment: @til_b: Well, this is exactly what I was talking about...  Good find :)

Comment: I asked myself the same question, and put some pieces together to get a working prototype.
**So far it works great**, with no scalability problems from several millions up to hundreds millions of points with around 20 attributes each. With this many points, finding points inside an area **takes a few hundred millis**. It takes about the same time to filter by timestamp (precise time of acquisition for me). On the overall the perf are same or better than in *"LiDAR Data Management Pipeline; from Spatial Database Population to Web-Application Visualization"* Data is compressed into DB (about 1:2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a lot in your question. The short answer is yes, it is completely possible to store huge point cloud data in PostGIS and use it for processing. We've built such a full system that does this.

This video is a little out of date with it's numbers but we had TBs of mobile/terrestrial and aerial data in postgis accessible through python for processing in the back end and with a web front end allowing 3D viewing and downloading of the data.
https://vimeo.com/39053196

It really comes down to how you choose to store the data in PostGIS and how you are going to be accessing it. A good solution for aerial data might well be to grid the data in some way and use multipoints for efficiency. However, if you are working with mobile or terrestrial data where the point density can be between 500-30000+ points per metre squared this approach doesn't work. Then it comes down to looking at your hardware and the number of concurrent users you expect. 
Details about this can be found in some of our papers 
http://www.mendeley.com/profiles/conor-mc-elhinney/

Comment: Hi, thanks for so many detailed information. The ides/tests offered in your papers seem really useful! It will take me some time to see it all through but as I saw on a first read, they already provide whole workarounds. Thanks a lot for the adding! Also the video and your browser-based pc-viewer is quite interesting and seem to work very well and smooth! Unfortunately I got my hands short-termed on other stuff. I hope to continue with pc-data shortly though.

Comment: The Glimpse project has a really cool demo here: http://ncg.nuim.ie/glimpse/auth/login.php

Answer (score 7):

(The answer is based on my and others' comments above; haven't really tested it)

Store the points as MultiPointZM. The best grid size would probably be dependent on access patterns and you need to do some testing on this. A regular grid with a spatial index should make queries quite fast. If 3d access is important then MultiPointZM could be 3D block based(1) instead of a 2D plane grid, then (if you have PostGIS >= 2.0) you would be able to use &&& for fast 3D queries.

You could also store the grid pattern in a separate table, which might be useful e.g. when updating the data and validating that the MultiPointZM blocks stay within their bounds after edits etc.

Storing timestamps or other data would only be possible for a block at a time, but some binary / category data could be stored by disaggregating each block by attribute if there are not too many categories and/or attributes.

If you end up having to store the data as separate PointZM, then a foreign key on the grid table + B-Tree index would make loading only the specific points (probably) a lot faster than just queyrying the table directly, even with a spatial index.

(1) If the range of Z-values is small (it's a road, after all), this probably does not make sense.

Comment: I think your 'summary' hits pretty well in as a conclusion of the former discussed proposals. As you said, the 'right' way to load such data must be figured out within the needs and proposed solutions. It turned out, not to be impossible thanks to so many ideas. It gave me a lot of inspiration for my further work on this issue. Thanks a lot!